# Update a table based on the count of specific records in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server and I have a table shown below in my database:

```
Id   groupName    flag    type 
--------------------------------
1    aaa          0        0   
2    aaa          1        0 
3    aaa          0        0 
4    bbb          0        0   
5    bbb          0        0 
6    bbb          0        0
```

I'd like to update the `type` column values based on the count of specific records in the same table.

Assuming that the records are grouped by their `groupName`, if a group has at least 1 record whose `flag` = 1, the `type`values of all the records in the same group should be 1, else 0.

In my case, I'd like to get the following output.

```
Id   groupName    flag    type 
--------------------------------
1    aaa          0        1   
2    aaa          1        1 
3    aaa          0        1 
4    bbb          0        0   
5    bbb          0        0 
6    bbb          0        0
```

How can I do this with a SQL statement?

**Edit**

The following, of course, does not work.

```
UPDATE t1 
SET type = CASE
              WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tg) > 0) 
                 THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
           END 
FROM [sampleDB].[dbo].[groups] t1 
JOIN (SELECT t2.groupName, t2.flag 
      FROM [sampleDB].[dbo].[groups] t2) tg ON tg.groupName = t1.groupName 
                                            AND tg.flag = 1;
```

Comment: @Dale K The following does not work. UPDATE t1
SET type = 
 CASE
  WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tg) > 0) THEN 1
  ELSE 0
 END
FROM [sampleDB].[dbo].[groups] t1
JOIN (SELECT t2.groupName, t2.flag
   FROM [sampleDB].[dbo].[groups] t2) tg
   ON tg.groupName = t1.groupName 
   AND tg.flag = 1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
UPDATE t
SET
    type = case when cnt>=1 then 1 else 0 end
FROM 
    tablename t
    INNER JOIN (select group_name, count(case when flag=1 then 1 end) as cnt from tablename 
                group by group_name)t1
        ON t.group_name= t1.group_name
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This PERFECTLY worked for me!! I got stuck because I didn't understand how to use `count(case when flag=1 then 1 end)`. You taught me the correct usage.

Answer (score 2):

I would use window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select g.*, max(flag) over (partition by groupname) as new_flag
      from [sampleDB].[dbo].[groups] g
     )
update toupdate
    set flag = new_flag
    where flag <> new_flag;
```

Note the `where` clause so only rows where the flag is changing are updated.  SQL Server attempts to update row even when no values change, incurring overhead.  The `where` clause saves most of this overhead.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most performant way to solve this problem by using exists statement:

```
update t1
set type = 1
from table t1
where exists ( select 1 
               from table t2 
               where t1.groupname = t2.groupname 
               and flag = 1
              )
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by using a simple JOIN as:

```
UPDATE D
SET Type = 1
FROM Data D JOIN
(
  SELECT GroupName
  FROM Data
  WHERE Flag = 1
) T ON D.GroupName = T.GroupName;
```

Here is a [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06efd033190a65d47b488ece6e48447d)

Answer (score -1):

This could be other option

```
    ;with data
    As (
        Select count(groupname) groupname
               ,max(flag) flag
               ,type

         From Tablename
       Group by type
       Having count(groupname)>1
           And max(flag)=1
)
Update c
Set type =1
From data c
```